# How to request Campaign PErformance Report using Python from Bing Ads API?

Tags: python, bing, bing-ads-api

I was trying to request data from Bing Ads using this code:

```
import requests

# Replace these variables with your own data
client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
client_secret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
tenant_id = 'YOUR_TENANT_ID'
account_id = 'YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID'
customer_id = 'YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID'
refresh_token = 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'  # Obtain this through the OAuth flow

# Get access token
def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, refresh_token):
    token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token'
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'resource': 'https://ads.microsoft.com'
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()['access_token']

# Call the API to retrieve data
def get_campaign_data(access_token, account_id, customer_id):
    api_url = f'https://api.ads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13/CampaignPerformanceReportRequest'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'DeveloperToken': 'YOUR_DEVELOPER_TOKEN',  # Obtain this from your Bing Ads account
        'CustomerId': customer_id,
        'AccountId': account_id
    }
    # Define your report request here (refer to the API documentation for the correct format)
    report_request = {}
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=report_request)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.content

# Example usage
try:
    access_token = get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, refresh_token)
    campaign_data = get_campaign_data(access_token, account_id, customer_id)
    print(campaign_data)
except requests.HTTPError as e:
    print(f'An HTTP error occurred: {e.response.status_code}')
```

But for some reason I only get errors 401, any idea what is wrong? For my `tenant_id`, I'm using "common" and for `customer_id/account_id`,  I'm using `clid`, and aid from Bing Ads campaign page (params from url).
Refresh token was generated like a 5 days ago so should still be valid. Developer token was from developer Bing ads with super admin generated.

Export data from Bing Ads with Python code to get detailed view (`CampaignPerformanceReportRequest`)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).